# How do you access and modify data on an IDB file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, mysql, database

I am running a mobile and web app off of Docker, the data is stored in a mysql folder under various files with extension .idb

Is there a way to modify this data directly in the server i.e. using PUTTY or even WINSCP? It looks like jumbled code if I open the file with VIM or Notepad.

Thanks!

Comment: It is a bad idea to modify the database files on disk. It is a good idea to actually connect to the database with MySQL Workbench

Comment: how do I even read the data in Ubuntu through putty?  
What are the steps to connect MySQL workbench to that ibd file?

Comment: No, you shouldn't connect anything to the ibd. You should start the database server, or copy it to another database server and start that server. Then connect the workbench to the server